# MySQL: Finding the database username

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to simply print to a webpage the SQL version I am using, this is the code provided from my teacher, I have put in my server and the database, I don't know how to find my DB username and if it has a password.

```
// add here your connection details
String connectionString = "SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=dblogin;"
+ "UID=YOUR_DB_USERNAME; PASSWORD='';";
// create and open a connection to the database
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
// print the MySQL version in a console
ReturnError.Text = ("MySQL version: " + connection.ServerVersion);
// this line will prevent the console from closing immediately
 // to close the console just press any key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

during installation of mysql it usually asks for `root` username and password, try `root` with empty password, if it doesn't work - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html